# Prevent a new prototyped method to appear in for loop for keys in object

Tags: javascript

I have a function which I want to make it available to all objects.
Its the mergeObject(object) function as defined below :

```
Object.prototype.mergeObjects = function(object){
    if (typeof object != "object") return;
    for(var key in object){
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key))
            this[key] = object[key];
    }
    return this;
}
```

I have a variable events which is :

```
events : {
    "click #retryBtn":"onRetryBtnClick",
    "click #cancelBtn":"onCancelBtnClick",
    "click .dialogButton":"onDialogBtnClick"
}
```

This is a backbone's events json Object.

when I try to run a for loop for keys in events

```
for (var key in events) 
{
    console.log(key) 
}
```

It prints out

```
click #retryBtn
click #cancelBtn
click .dialogButton
mergeObjects
```

I dont understand why I get "mergeObjects" as key in "events" object.

The structure of events object is :

```
click #cancelBtn: "onCancelBtnClick"
click #retryBtn: "onRetryBtnClick"
click .dialogButton: "onDialogBtnClick"
__proto__: Object
    __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
    __defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
    __lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
    __lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
    constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
    hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
    isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
    mergeObjects: function (object){                 
    propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
    toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
    toString: function toString() { [native code] }
    valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
    get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
    set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
```

Can anyone explain me why "mergeObject" is part of the for loop keys?

How can I avoid it? Since there are other methods like "__defineGetter" which doesnt appear in the for loop keys.

Comment: Adding methods to `Object.prototype` is rarely a good idea, since it interested badly with the use of objects as dictionaries

Comment: just dont add method on `Object.prototype`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mergeObjects` is enumerable property( meaning it can be accessed using for in) which is being inherited by `events` object whereas methods like `__defineGetter` are non-enumerable(can't be accessed by for in).

[for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops traverse all the enumerable properties of the object including properties in the prototype chain as well.

Use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to avoid the inherited properties and get only direct enumerable property.

```
for (var key in events) 
{
    if(events.hasOwnProperty(key))
    console.log(key) 
}
```

If you want all the direct properties of an object either enumerable or non-enumerable( set using [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with enumerable false ) then you should iterate over [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)(IE9+) like

```
var keys = events.getOwnPropertyNames(); 
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
{
    console.log(keys[i]) 
}
/*
Or using forEach
events.getOwnPropertyNames().forEach(function(key){
    console.log(key);
})
*/
```

Additional Link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

**EDIT**: In order to not get `mergeObjects` inside for in loops use `Object.defineProperty` with enumerable false like

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'mergeObjects', {
  value: function(object){
             if (typeof object != "object") return;
                 for(var key in object){
                    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key))
                        this[key] = object[key];
                 }
             return this;
   },
   enumerable:false  //no need for this statement as default is false
});
```

It works in IE9 and above

Comment: Yes I can do this in my code. But there is an issue : 
The above for loop was just an example. Such a for loop exists in Backbone framework, it iterates through the keys in events object, and thats where my code crashes. I cannot change It. So basically the for loop is not in my hand. I want to do something with my method which will prevent it from appearing in the loop.. Please give me another solution.

Comment: then define your method as non-enumerable using `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasOwnProperty` to skip inherited properties:

```
for (var key in events) 
{
    if (events.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do this in my code. But there is an issue : The above for loop was just an example. Such a for loop exists in Backbone framework, it iterates through the keys in events object, and thats where my code crashes. I cannot change It. So basically the for loop is not in my hand. I want to do something with my method which will prevent it from appearing in the loop.. Please give me another solution

Comment: I'm very surprised that code for looping over an object in a popular framework doesn't already do this.